# Recursive query to mimic a folder structure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to mimic a simple folder structure in PostgreSQL using this table:

```
CREATE TABLE folders (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    parent UUID REFERENCES folders(id)
);
```

I have some simple data (id simplified):

```
(1, "parent", NULL)
(2, "child of 1", 1)
(3, "child of 2", 2)
(4, "other parent", NULL)
```

I've created this recursive query using some previous posts:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recursive_cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent
    FROM folders
    WHERE parent IS NULL -- Start with the root items (where parent is NULL)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT f.id, f.name, f.parent
    FROM folders f
    JOIN recursive_cte rc ON f.parent = rc.id
)
SELECT id, name, 
  (
      SELECT json_agg(json_build_object('id', c.id, 'name', c.name))
      FROM recursive_cte c
      WHERE c.parent = folders.id
  ) AS children
FROM folders
WHERE parent IS NULL;
```

My data returned is:

```
id, name, children[]
(1, "parent", [{"id":2, "name":"child of 1"}])
(4, "other parent", [])
```

What are the steps required to modify my query so that I can recursively build down the "children" column to have the json also contain any childs?

Comment: If you can, define a recursive function, it's much simpler

Answer (score -1):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE recursive_cte AS (
    SELECT id, name, parent, jsonb_build_object('id', id, 'name', name) AS json_data
    FROM folders
    WHERE parent IS NULL -- Start with the root items (where parent is NULL)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT f.id, f.name, f.parent, jsonb_build_object('id', f.id, 'name', f.name) || rc.json_data
    FROM folders f
    JOIN recursive_cte rc ON f.parent = rc.id
)
SELECT id, name, jsonb_agg(json_data) AS children
FROM recursive_cte
GROUP BY id, name
ORDER BY id;
```

use the jsonb_build_object function to create a JSON object for each folder in the recursive common table expression, this JSON object includes the 'id' and 'name' of the folder and then, use the || operator to concatenate the current folder's JSON data with the JSON data of its parent folder in the recursive CTE; getting the hierarchy in the JSON structure built.